# Keep snackbar open after action

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I use a snackbar to notify the users of my app that some errors occur. Now I want the snackbar to stay displayed while `fatalError` is not empty

```
fatalError = [some,errors];

var snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(
  this.fatalError.length + ' Fatal Error(s)', 'See'
);
```

When the user click on see, he can mark all error as read and then fatalError get empty

How to keep the snackBar open after clicking on action ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may achieve that using a custom snackBar component.

On your custom component template include your message and buttons for the actions you need.

Then you may inject `MatSnackBar` on your component and on the button click handlers you may decide wether or not to dismiss the snackBar (which may be done by using `dismiss` method from `MatSnackBar`)

I've forked [material snackBar example](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples) and created an example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmgyvn?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-component-example.ts).

Comment: Work great ! Thank you so much